# Error when creating ul with recursion in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion

I'm trying to create a React component with recursion on a list of items, but JS shows "InternalError: too much recursion" and I can't see where the mistake is.

Looking for recommendations on what I need learn to solve this. I don't know if the method I used to create the nested list is the best, and I'm try to solve this problem with recursion, but I'm still open to new patterns.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Service from '../itemOrcamento/Service'

class Ul extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          lista: [],
        }
    }


  componentDidMount(){
    Service.carregarLista(this.props.id)
    .then(lista => {
      this.setState({
        lista: lista.data,
      })
    })
  }

  buscaFilhos(item){
    let filhos = []
    let items = this.state.lista
    items.map( filho => {
      if (filho.codigo_item_pai == item.codigo_item_pai) filhos.push(filho) 
    })
    this.criaListaFilhos(filhos)
  }

  criaListaFilhos(filhos){
    return (
      <ul>
        {filhos.map( filho => {
          return (
            <li>{filho.codigo_cliente}, ordem: {filho.numero_sequencia}
              {this.buscaFilhos(filho)} 
            </li>

          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  makeList(itens) {
    if (itens.length) {
      let lista = itens.map((item, key) => {
        if (item.fields.codigo_item_pai) return
        return (
          <div>
              <li> item: {item.fields.codigo_cliente}, ordem: {item.fields.numero_sequencia} </li>
              {this.buscaFilhos(item)}
          </div>
          )
      })
      return lista
    }
    return
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.makeList(this.state.lista)} 
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Ul;
```

Comment: `this.criaListaFilhos(filhos)` -> `filhos.map( filho => {` -> `this.buscaFilhos(filho)` -> infinite recursion

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I get the feeling that
`if (filho.codigo_item_pai == item.codigo_item_pai)` should be instead looking at a parent id of some kind, otherwise you're mapping an item onto itself and recursing again.

Comment: Thank you @James your feelings was right! now recursion works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merging craListaFilhos? and BuscaFilos?

```
Promise.all(items.map( filho => {
      if (filho.codigo_item_pai == item.codigo_item_pai) filhos.push(filho) 
    })).then(() => {
return (
      <ul>
        {filhos.map( filho => {
          return (
            <li>{filho.codigo_cliente}, ordem: {filho.numero_sequencia}
              {this.buscaFilhos(filho)} 
            </li>

          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )


}
```